# ImportError with cPickle

Tags: python, pickle, importerror

I've looked through the various replies to related cPickle questions, but none seem to help. Neither does using cloudpickle instead of cPickle.

I have a module named MyModule that defines a class MyClass

First, I run a script in a different folder from my project folder. I import my own class MyClass from the project, make an instance of the class and pickle it at target path.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ.get("PROJECT_ROOT"), 'src/'))
from MyModule import MyClass
class_instance = MyClass()
with gzip.open(os.path.join(target_path, 'net.p.gz'), "wb") as f:
    cPickle.dump(class_instance, f)
```

Then, in my main project, I want to load the pickled file

```
from MyModule import MyClass
with gzip.open(os.path.join(os.environ['PROJECT_ROOT'], 'resources/net.p.gz'), 'rb') as f:
        class_instance = cPickle.load(f)
```

This results in an

```
ImportError: No module named MyModule
```

However

```
test_instance = MyClass()
print (test_instance)
```

in the same file prints

```
<MyModule.MyClass object at 0x7fad03e3ead0>
```

So the module is obviously there and being improted.

Both times I am referring to the same module, it does not change location. What am I missing?

Comment: @gplayer You're right. My mistake was that I thought since I'm already in ~/work/repo/ it's in the path. Do you want to repost this as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have MyModule here: `~/work/repo/my_module.py`. If you want `from MyModule import MyClass` to work, then you have to have this on the python path: `~/work/repo`. Try to do a `import sys; print sys.path` and check it out.